# Spring Batch CompositeProcessor each processor has jdbcTemplate, 2nd processor says it's null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Good day.
I'm working on a spring batch process that has a step with one reader, a composite processor, and a composite writer.
The first processor uses a data source/jdbc template to read record for information and either passes the record from the writer or not.  The next processor has the same configuration for data source/jdbc template, and is set the same way in the java config bean (Spring Boot), but the jdbc template is coming up null.
I have a data source setter in each processor, which then creates the jdbc template, already defined in the processor.
The processors are set to '@JobScope', so they can use command-line parameters to determine some actions during the process.

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public FirstProcessor firstProcessor() {
    FirstProcessor firstProcessor = 
            new FirstProcessor();
    firstProcessor.setDataSource( dbReaderDataSource() );
    return firstProcessor;
}

@Bean
@JobScope
public SecondProcessor secondProcessor() {
    SecondProcessor secondProcessor = new SecondProcessor();
    secondProcessor.setDataSource( dbReaderDataSource() );
    return secondProcessor;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DriverManagerDataSource dbReaderDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    String urlStr = "<url>";
    String driverStr = "<driver class name>";
    String usernameStr = "<userid>";
    String passwordStr = "<password>";
    dataSource.setUrl( urlStr );
    log.info("Setting Driver Class to: " + driverStr);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName( driverStr );
    dataSource.setUsername( usernameStr );
    dataSource.setPassword( passwordStr );

    return dataSource;
}
```

...in my processors, I define the JdbcTemplate using:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

....and set it using a setter:

```
public void setDataSource( DriverManagerDataSource dS ) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate( dS );
}
```

The first processor works fine: the second throws the NPE when I do 
a query For List(....)" call.

I've also tried setting up a Driver Manager Data Source object in the processors, 
and using that to create the Jdbc Template if I find it is null before doing 
the query. I got:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
...when I try to set the jdbcTemplate datasource within the processor.

Any advice would be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use @Autowired on the constructors, and let Spring scan for the dependency to inject before the instance is created.

```
@Autowired
public FirstProcessor(DriverManagerDataSource ds)
{
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dS);
}
```

and

```
@Autowired
public SecondProcessor(DriverManagerDataSource ds)
{
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Edd. Are you talking about the constructors in the java config, or in the processor beans themselves ?

Comment: In the definition of your classes themselves, the code. Just like any normal constructor that you would use in a normal class, just put Autowired at the top like I wrote above. Spring will scan for it and inject the dependency (that was annotated as a Bean, which you did)

Comment: I added the @Autowired for my bean, like this:  <code> (autowired annot>, <Scope annotation>
public class FirstProcessor 
     implements ItemProcessor<DTO1, DTO1> {
 
 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstProcessor.class.getName());
 
</code>  ...and it gave me error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration.  We're using Java 1.7, Spring 4.3.5, SpringBatch 3.0.7, SpringBoot 1.3.0, SpringBootStarterBatch 1.2.7.

Comment: Tom, when you look at the imports statements you have at the top of your code, what do you have there for Autowired ? is it `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the import I'm using.  As it turns out, someone else here mentioned that I really needed to @Autowire the JdbcTemplate, not the Beans themselves.  That does work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad to hear that it turned out ok at the end, one way or another

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon.  I managed to get two processors working with the autowired jdbcTemplate, but when I added one or two more processors that were configured the same way, I'm now getting a StackOverflow error on the 3rd processor.  Spring says it threw "IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations on public <package>.MyJavaConfig.jdbcTemplate".  I have jdbcTemplate autowired, plus I have a setter for it in the processor beans.

Comment: Back to grindstone my friend. Stackoverflow error you said? Try to remove the setter, still the same error?

Comment: As it turns out, the StackOverflowError turned out to be a typo on my part.  I had one of my javaconfig beans returning not a processor object, but a call to create the processor object  ( return secondProcessor(); instead of return secondProcessor; )  And in the case of the jdbcTemplate being null, we decided to create a bean jdbcTemplate in the javaconfig, using the datasource we already had configured.  We then took out all the jdbcTemplate setters in our processors, and that was what worked for us.  Unfamiliarity with Spring Batch and Spring Boot didn't help the situation. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. Spring has a bit of steep learning curve (especially with the xml config against notation) but it's worth the effort